# Send email notification when values in different columns increase

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet with an array of values that goes from A1 to BK288. This array is a percentage calculation based on another spreadsheet that updates every 5 minutes. Now I would like to receive an email notification when one value on the same row in different columns increase and become greater then a fixed value. Then the email should contain that volue on the body and the title of the column on the subject. 
I wrote this script but is for a single cell, I don't know if there is a way to extend it for every column, apart writing a function for every column. Also, is there a way to trigger an automatic notification? Consider the sheet updates the values every 5 minutes. Thanks

```
function getValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Perc");
  var value = sheet.getRange("A288").getValue();
  var title = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  if(value >= "2") sendEmail(value, title)
};


function sendEmail(value, title){
  var recipient="someemail@gmail.com";
  var subject=title + " price";
  var body=title + " price has changed by " + value + "%";
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
};
```

Comment: So each row have a different fixed value to compare to ? Where is this value on your sheet ? Can you provide us a sample of your sheet, for interpretation purpose ?

Comment: The fixed value is 2, and each column on the same row has a different value which is a percentage calculation. For example: A288=0, B288=0.5448800619, C288=-0.2566428034, D288=0.2315139654, E288=-0.8245011437, F288=-0.2449391254, ..., BK288=0.5229186801. When one of this value is equal or greater than 2 I would like to receive an email notification as in the function above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution.

The data are put on a array and process column one after one other. I also add a solution when multiple product changed, so only one mail is send with all the informations needed, to prevend the daily quota to be reached.

*Edit: Only analyse row 288*

```
function compareValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Perc");
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var list = []; // List of change greater than 2

  for(var i=0; i<data[0].length; i++){

    var title = data[0][i]; // Get the title of the element
    var value = parseFloat(data[data.length -1][i]); // Get the value on last row (288th)

    if(value >= 2){ // If the value greater than 2, add it on a list

      var element = [title, value];

      list.push(element)

    }
  }

  if(list.length == 1){ // If only 1 element changing, send classic mail
    sendEmail(list[0][1], list[0][0]);
  }
  if(list.length >= 2){ // If 2 or more element changing, send mail with all the change
    sendEmail(list);
  }
}

function sendEmail(value, title){
  var recipient="pierre.marie.richard@gmail.com";
  var subject=title + " price";
  var body=title + " price has changed by " + value + "%";
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}

function sendEmail(list){
  var recipient="pierre.marie.richard@gmail.com";
  var subject="Multiples prices have changed";
  var body = "";
  for(var i=0; i<list.length;i++){ // Get throught the list to write the body
    body=body + list[i][0] + " price has changed by " + list[i][1] + "\%\n";
  }
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much. But it seems like the function is taking every value from A2 to BK288 (first row is for the titles), so I get a notification for every changes in every rows. I only need the changes in the last row, the 288th. Also, should I set a trigger to run the function every 5 minutes, to check if there is any changes? thank you again

Comment: Oh, I was assuming that you want to take all change, since you talk about "an array of values that goes from A1 to BK288". I'll take some modification.

Comment: The modification is done. If you want to add a trigger, you can add it with code [look here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) or put it with the interface and place it on compareValue() function

Comment: Yes, the array is because every row is the change in percentage of a price compared with the same price 5 minutes earlier. But I only need the last prices change, which are in row 288. Anyway, you already helped me a lot with this code, I'm still studying how to manage a big array like this. I try to understand your code now

Comment: I've add some comment to help you on understanding

Comment: Ok, the script works fine when there are multiple changes, but when there is only 1 change I get an empty email with "Multiple prices have changed" as subject. So I removed the two "if" to run different functions to send email and just left `sendEmail(list)`. Thank you again @Pierre-Marie Richard