# Copy cells to another sheet when values increase

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Yesterday I asked this question: [Send email notification when values in different columns increase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44778734/send-email-notification-when-values-in-different-columns-increase)
Basically, I have an array of percentage calculations, and if the values in different columns on the last row change and meet the increase criteria, they should be copied on another sheet.

I tried to change the code accordingly:

```
function compareValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Perc");
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var list = []; 

  for(var i=0; i<data[0].length; i++){

    var title = data[0][i]; 
    var value = parseFloat(data[data.length -1][i]); /

    if(value >= 2){     
      var element = [title, value];    
      list.push(element)                
    }    
  }

  if(list.length >= 1){ 
    setValues(list);
  }
}


function setValues(list) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Alert");
  sheet.getRange('A1:Z50').clearContent();
  var title = sheet.getRange(1, 1, list.length);
  var value = sheet.getRange(1, 2, list.length);

  for(var i=0; i<list.length;i++){
    title.setValue(list[i][0]);
    value.setValue(list[i][1]);
  }

}
```

Now the problem is when I have only one cell that changed everything is fine, but when there are multiple cells the script only copy one value, and it is repeated for the number of values that should be. For example, if 4 cells increase over the value 2, then only one value is copied and it is repeated 4 times. What am I doing wrong? thank you

Comment: From this code, you analyse only the 288th row of your array. If you want to set the change on all the values, you must add a loop for row analysing.

Comment: Hi Pierre-Marie, I just need to analyze the last row, as yesterday. But now I want to copy the values in another sheet instead of sending an email. I tried to change your code but it doesn't work in my way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on your value set. On your code, you set the value for the all range with the last value on the list, cause it's the last value on your for loop. Consider using [range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) which is simple to use.

```
function compareValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Perc");
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var list = []; 

  for(var i=0; i<data[0].length; i++){

    var title = data[0][i]; 
    var value = parseFloat(data[data.length -1][i]);

    if(value >= 2){     
      var element = [title, value];    
      list.push(element)                
    }    
  }

  if(list.length >= 1){ 
    setValues(list);
  }
}


function setValues(list) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Alert");
  sheet.getRange('A1:Z50').clearContent();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, list.length, list[0].length);

  range.setValues(list);

}
```

Comment: Wow, that was so simple. I used the range.setValues so many times in other sheets that I should be ashamed for not thinking about it! Since you used the for loop in the email sending I was thinking it was the only way to manage the list. Thank you very much, you helped me a lot again!